# Deploy failing on Docker Tomcat

Tags: java, docker, spring-mvc, tomcat

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /docker-java-home/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.111 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.115 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 5 2019 11:42:42 UTC
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.117 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.38.0
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.119 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.120 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.125-linuxkit
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.121 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.124 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.125 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.126 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.127 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.128 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.130 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.130 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.132 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.134 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.135 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.136 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.137 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.139 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.5.2].
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.140 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.141 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.151 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.274 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.296 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.327 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.334 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.336 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 873 ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.374 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.375 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.38
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.503 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setPath A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.510 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/com.gdn.x.ui-mobile-api.war]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:33.550 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
13-Mar-2019 12:00:38.942 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/com.gdn.x.ui-mobile-api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2159)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

13-Mar-2019 12:00:38.953 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/com.gdn.x.ui-mobile-api.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/com.gdn.x.ui-mobile-api]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

13-Mar-2019 12:00:38.960 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/com.gdn.x.ui-mobile-api.war] has finished in [5,449] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:38.963 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.109 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [146] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.110 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.441 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [331] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.503 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [52] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.505 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.552 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [47] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.557 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.608 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [52] ms
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.626 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.649 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Mar-2019 12:00:39.654 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 6315 ms
```

I am trying to deploy docker spring mvc application through tomcat but even though the build succeeds, the app fails to deploy on tomcat. I don't quite understand the error and I tried absolute ordering inside the web.xml. But still, the error persists. Please help me out. 
I am using IntelliJ Ultimate IDE 
Maven version is 3.6 and the tomcat being used is 8.5.38
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8 as builder
COPY . /usr/src/mymaven
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
RUN chmod +x ./docker.sh
COPY ./docker.sh /usr/local/tomcat/
COPY ./app-config /usr/local/tomcat

RUN mvn clean -DskipTests install -f /usr/src/mymaven && mkdir /usr/src/wars/
RUN find /usr/src/mymaven/ -iname '*.war' -exec cp {} /usr/src/wars/ \;

FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install procps

FROM redis
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]

FROM tomcat:8.5.38-jre8
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/wars/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Here, I have added the dockerfile

EDIT: I have tried fixing the pom.xml file and included absolute ordering, 
still no luck. 
I tried rebuilding the whole image again, that too has no solution
The deploy gets successfully built on local but fails in docker.

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile?

Comment: I have added the dockerfile in the post now @SamuelPhilipp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one fragment with the name \[spring\_web\] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w)

Comment: I tried fixing that, I also added absolute ordering tag to the pom file, still no luck

Comment: Can you please also share your pom.xml?

Comment: Fixed it using the absolute-ordering tag inside the project-context.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

```
<absolute-ordering><name>spring_web</name></absolute-ordering>
```

in the project-context.xml file and it worked.

Greetings.