# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, web.xml

I am using tomcat 7 in eclipse(not maven). X project is working fine but when i am running Y project(dynamic web project) it is giving following error. I have tried many solutions like cleaning project and every possible solution that i found in stackoverflow, But nothing worked

Jars in lib folder of project.

[image: jars in lib folder of project are]

```
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.93
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 16 2019 17:13:17 UTC
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.93.0
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\uday\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Udayg\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.93
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\uday\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Udayg\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.93
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\uday\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Udayg\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.93\endorsed
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;E:\eclipse;;.
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8060"]
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1045 ms
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.93
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [156] milliseconds.
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1268)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5590)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1268)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5590)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIRLAADMINPIVC]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1268)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5590)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8060"]
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8060"]
Mar 18, 2019 12:45:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

my web.xml file is

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ADMINPIVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BIRLAADMINPIVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/BIRLAADMINPIVC-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

my adminpivc-servlet.xml file is

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.bhartiaxa.controller" />
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:yyy.properties" />
        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@yyyyy:1521:XE" />
            <property name="username" value="yyyyy" />
            <property name="password" value="yyyyy" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
            <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"></bean>
    </beans>
```

Comment: You have multiple versions of `spring-web` artifact on your classpath. This can lead to arbitrary issues.

Comment: Am a bit confused why you ask the question for a problem you already solved as written here: [More than one fragment with the name (spring_web) was found. This is not legal with relative ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w)