# More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found

Tags: spring-boot

Got this while deploying the spring boot war on tomcat. 
Anyone got this error
I have below steps :

Pom.xml :
    
        
            org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-web
            
                
                    org.springframework.boot
                    spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Main Class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one fragment with the name \[spring\_web\] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w)

Comment: No its different from it.. Any way its worked fine when deployed on another tomcat.. Still in a search for the proper reason of the error..

Comment: @Jang2212 Any solution u found??