# CAS 5.3 Management - More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have the exact same problem as described in the below post, but I don't know how to implement the solution with the 5.3 branch of the cas-management-overlay. I can't seem to figure out where to add the absolute-ordering tag (in web.xml) and what names to put in it. My web.xml just has a couple of servlets and a bunch of mime-mapping. Most of the solutions I've seen for this seem to be people writing their own stuff.

Also, I'm not sure if the conflict is internal to this overlay or if it's between the spring version of CAS and CAS managment. They both show different different spring versions in pom.xml. I tried making them the same and building, but it didn't work.

I'd appreciate any suggestions that might point me in the right direction.

https://github.com/apereo/cas-management-overlay

[More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w/56261786#56261786)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and solved it.
You can exclude the `spring-web` jar while you import some `service-registry` dependency.

```xml
<!-- redis service registry-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-redis-service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Because both the `cas-management-webapp.5.x.x.war` and the `xx-service-registry` jar use two different `spring-web` jars.

My cas-management-webapp version is 5.3.6 and cas version is 5.3.5.

spring-web'version is 4.3.17 in `cas-management-webapp.5.3.6.war` but 4.3.20 in `cas-server-support-redis-service-registry` jar.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody reading this, I "solved" the problem by removing (see renaming) one of the fragments (read jar files) so that there was no ordering conflict. I'm not really sure why there are two version, but I did

mv /var/lib/tomcat/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar /var/lib/tomcat/cas-management/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar_save20190605

in order to make the older version inaccessible and it worked. Also, a slightly unrelated problem, but if you are running the 5.3 management overlay, you will run into this issue. You have to remove the cas. prefix from the setting in etc/cas/config/management.properties, otherwise you will get errors like "Invalid property 'mgmt[userPropertiesFile]" for different properties in the file.