# Unable to start tomcat server for spring mvc application in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I was trying to build a small spring mvc app in eclipse. When i run the project on Server by Selecting **Run as-> Run on server** i got the following error

```
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.24
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Aug 14 2019 21:16:42 UTC
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version number: 9.0.24.0
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            4.15.0-60-generic
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Private Build
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/sachinmukherjee/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/sachinmukherjee/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/sachinmukherjee/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Server initialization in [795] milliseconds
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more

    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more

    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-mvc-demo]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2257)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2215)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more

    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Sep 12, 2019 6:47:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

All my controller code resides under the package

**com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc**

Java version - 1.8

Spring version - 5.1

Two of my configration files look likes this

**spring-mvc-demo.servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc" />


    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->


    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

        <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

        <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

        <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

I'm new to spring and i dont know why this is happening. Whether it is server side issue to some error in my code.

Comment: may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w

Comment: Is it an eclipse project (not maven)? How your project is configured, probably two sources folder point the same web.xml, duplicating it. If maven, check the Suraj's answer.

Comment: @DavidGard Suraj's answer worked. but i don't know why this was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<absolute-ordering/>` tag in your web.xml below the `<display-name>` tag.

This has already been answered. Please check the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w).

Comment: Thanks it worked but i don't know why this was happening.