# Spring and spring-security and spring-ws matching versions

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two projects where one includes the war of the other.

First one has defined properties

```
        <org.springframework.version>5.0.9.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.ws.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.ws.version>
```

With dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And that passes enforcer rules.

The second project includes some of the first project's modules as war, some as jars, all at compile time, and additionally has defined

```
        <org.springframework.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.ws.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.ws.version>
```

for

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.ws.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This also passes enforcer rules, but since I have different versions of Spring Framework included through wars, all of them get deployed I run into this issue: [More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290263/more-than-one-fragment-with-the-name-spring-web-was-found-this-is-not-legal-w)

In case I change the spring framework version in second project to 5.0.9, Maven Enforcer does not pass so I can't do that. To make it pass, I've tried excluding spring-expression artifact out of some jars, but when I do that, my login screen loses it's styling and God knows what else is broken.

How can I find the matching versions of these libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Setting explicitly the version of each Spring library in the POM is a bad practice.

If you use Spring alone, the recommended solution is to use `spring-framework-bom`, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom#spring-bom

If you use Spring along with Spring Boot, the recommended solution is to use  `spring-boot-dependencies` or, even better, `spring-boot-starter-parent` (the latter also manages the version of many Maven plugins) as described in [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using) of the official documentation.

Even if you don't use Spring Boot, using `spring-boot-starter-parent` will allow you to manage automatically the versions of many well known libraries often used with Spring like Hibernate, Logback and Jackson.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't include packages from org.springframework.ws because it says that dependency version for spring-ws-security is missing.